# Finding a point of a rotation (complex numbers)

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, contest-math

I posted early but got a very tough response.

Point $A = 2 + 0i$ and point $B = 2 + i2\sqrt{3}$ find the point $C$ $60$ degrees ($\pm$) such that Triangle $ABC$ is equilateral.

Okay, so I'll begin by converting into polar form:

$A = 2e^{2\pi i}$ and $B = 4e^{\frac{\pi}{3}i}$

$\overline{AB} = \sqrt{13}$

How should I find a point with length $\overline{BC} = \overline{AC} = \sqrt{13}$ and the sufficient angle?

Answer (score 0):

Hint. If you want to rotate the vector $AB$ anticlockwise by $60^o$ you can multiply it by $e^{\frac{i\pi}{3}}$, so you can locate one of the possible points by adding this to $A$. Alternatively drawing a diagram and using trigonometry will identify the points.

Comment: how does multiplying by the exponential give the point?

Comment: If $z=re^{i\alpha}$ then $ze^{i\theta}=re^{i(\alpha+\theta)}$

Comment: Oh I see - Let $A=z$ in this case, then multiplying by $re^{i\theta}$ gives $re^{i(\alpha + \theta)}$ the length would be $2$ and the angle changed. So: $A = 2e^{2\pi i}$ then multiply by $e^{i \frac{\pi}{3}}$ to get: $A = 2e^{i\frac{7\pi}{3}}$. The angle is correct, just $2 \to \sqrt{13}$ and we get: $$\sqrt{13}e^{i\frac{7\pi}{3}} = \sqrt{13} \cdot \bigg[\frac{1}{2} + i\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\bigg] $$ But that is incorrect, why?

Comment: Rotate AB not OB

Comment: So $AB$ would the vector $(a-b)$?

Comment: The vector AB is B-A

Answer (score 0):

I think that you could shift the whole thing so that A is at origin. Then find a point $C'$ such that it satisfies your conditions and then un-shift (shift back) the whole thing. So, you get that $A' = 0$ and $B' = i2\sqrt{3}$ after the shift. You have one point at origin, another one on the imaginary axis. So, your third point should be (+/-) 60 degrees from the imaginary axis, i.e. at angles $\pi/6$ and $5\pi/6$. The absolute value (distance) for this point would be $2\sqrt{3}$. Now, shift all back by 2. Hope it helps.